# How to allow customers their own subdomain address to our web app?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, cname

We have a webapp and companies can customize the look and feel. Now we'd like them to be able to make the app part of their existing website by allowing them custom subdomains.

For example:

```
Our app         : www.ourapp.example  
Their site      : www.somecompany.example  
Their subdomain : ourapp.somecompany.example (shows ourapp.example)
```

**Note:** www.somecompany.example is an *existing* website, so we don't want to replace it with our site.

I tried adding a CNAME "ourapp" which points to `www.ourapp.example`, but it gives me a "Resource not found" error, probably because IIS does not know what to do with the incoming URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this if the DNS Zone Admin for `www.somecompany.example`  adds `ourapp.somecompany.example` as a subdomain entry pointing to the IP of `www.ourapp.example` on their DNS server and add `ourapp.somecompany.example` as a valid domain on your server in IIS.

Not knowing about IIS specifics, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737065/server-alias-in-iis could be of help.